# Show Hide Div's in Repeater Item Template

Tags: asp.net, jquery, repeater

I'm displaying summary and details customer info in each repeater row - inside the repeater .

The summary stuff is it's own div: (id="divHistory_Summary).  The details stuff in it's own div: (id="divHistory_details" )

The details div is hidden by default with inline style: display: none;

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterCustHistory" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>

                <div id="divHistory_Summary" class="cust_summary" style="width: 100%; cursor: pointer" >
                     <div id="divTicketNumber" style="display: inline; float: left;">
                          <u><strong>Ticket ID:</strong> <asp:Label ID="lblCustHelpDeskTicketId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HelpDesk_id") %>' /></u>
                     </div>  

                      <div id="divProblem" style="display: inline; float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
                         <strong>Problem:</strong> <asp:Label ID="lblProblem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HelpDesk_problem") %>' />
                     </div>

                     <div id="divStatus" style="display: inline; float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
                         <strong>Status:</strong> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HelpDesk_name") %>' />
                     </div>

                  </div>

                  <div id="divHistory_details" class="cust_details" style=" width: 100%; float: left; display: none;  ">
                      <strong>Solution:</strong> <asp:Label ID="lblSolution" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("HelpDesk_solution") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </div>

             </ItemTemplate>
          <SeparatorTemplate>
             <hr />
          </SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
   </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
```

At the bottom of my aspx page I have my jquery:

```
 <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>' type="text/javascript" ></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".cust_details").hide();
             $(".cust_summary").click(function () {
                $(this).next(".cust_details").slideToggle(100);
             });
         });

  </script>
```

I don't have the jquery.js file in the head of my app, so I hope it's ok to call the script right here.  This app has many nested master pages, and didn't know which one to put the call to jquery file.

The page loads, repeater populates, the details stuff is hidden. When clicking the summary div, nothing happens - the details stuff won't show.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this show/hide div to work like this? THank You!

I'm using VS2010, Framework 2.0, C#

Comment: Have you checked to see if any JavaScript errors occurred that might have prevented your code from running?  Your code looks fine to me at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(this).nextAll('div[class="cust_details"]').eq(0).slideToggle(100);
```

I have ran a quick test and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".cust_details").hide();
             $(".cust_summary").click(function () {
            $(this).nextAll('div[class="cust_details"]').eq(0).slideToggle(100);
             });
         });

</script>
```